# configuring a multihomed host as a router

Tags: networking, ip, iptables, home-networking

I have two linux hosts on my home network, host1 and host2. I'm trying to configure it so that host1 is connected to a vpn, and host2 can send packets out over the vpn by routing through host1. My naive attempt was to run

```
root@host1 # iptables -A FORWARD -i wlp2s0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
root@host1 # iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o wlp2s0 -j ACCEPT 
root@host1 # iptables -A INPUT -i wlp2s0 -j ACCEPT
root@host1 # iptables -A INPUT -i tun0  -j ACCEPT 
root@host1 # iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
root@host1 # iptables -A OUTPUT -o wlp2s0 -j ACCEPT
```

on the routing host, and

```
user@host2 $ sudo ip route add 104.24.122.145/32 via 10.0.0.76 dev wlp58s0
user@host2 $ curl 104.24.122.145 -H 'Host: ifconfig.io'
```

on the other host. The idea was that if everything behaved as expected, I could get my home ip address by hitting one of ifconfig.io's ips, and the vpn ip address by hitting the other one.

However, when I run that `curl` command it times-out, and the iptable logs don't seem to indicate that any traffic is hopping through. (Presumably the `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` packets are all from background traffic).

```
root@host1 # sudo iptables -L -vn 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    5   383 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    8   847 ACCEPT     all  --  wlp2s0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   wlp2s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  wlp2s0 tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    5   459 ACCEPT     all  --  *      wlp2s0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    2   151 ACCEPT     all  --  *      tun0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

What have I missed? I'm using [this](https://www.mad-hacking.net/documentation/linux/security/iptables/multihomed.xml) as a baseline for understanding. I haven't followed it exactly, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable ip forwarding:

1. Edit  /etc/sysctl.conf.  Uncomment the line

   `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
2. Reload the new settings:

   `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`